# CSS rules for form elements are effecting other forms on my website

Tags: css, forms

I'm trying to style the label, inputs and submit elements of a particular form using CSS.

The code I'm using looks like this:

```
    .newsletter_display label  {
width: 75px;
text-align:left;
}
.newsletter_display select {
    width: 60px;
}
.newsletter_display label,input,select {
    float:left;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
        color: #7F7F7F;
}

.newsletter_display label,input[type="submit"] {
    clear:left;
    }

.newsletter_display select,input[type="text"]  {
        color: #333;
    }
```

But the code is being used in other forms on the page that have nothing to do with this one and are not within the newsletter_display class. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: .newsletter_display label,input,select translates to the label as child of .newsletter_display and ALL input elements and ALL select elements. You need to write it as .newsletter_display label,.newsletter_display input,.newsletter_display select. Same goes the two rules beneath that one.

Answer (score 4):

Please update your css to the following. You are including others form inputs when you are not making it class specific.

```
.newsletter_display label  {
width: 75px;
text-align:left;
}
.newsletter_display select {
width: 60px;
}
.newsletter_display label, .newsletter_display input, .newsletter_display select {
float:left;
margin-top:5px;
margin-bottom:5px;
color: #7F7F7F;
}

.newsletter_display label, .newsletter_display input[type="submit"] {
clear:left;
}

.newsletter_display select, .newsletter_display input[type="text"]  {
color: #333;
}
```